# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I just implemented server-side rendering in my Angular 11 app and am faced with the following error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'
```

When I run `npm run dev:ssr`, everything works as expected, but when I run `ng deploy --preview`, the error is thrown.

This is my `server.ts` file:

```
// Polyfills required for Firebase
(global as any).WebSocket = require("ws");
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require("xhr2");

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

const domino = require('domino');
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
const win = domino.createWindow(indexHtml);

global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I'm a bit confused why the error is being thrown. How can I fix this issue? I'm pretty new to Angular Universal and would appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I have exactly the same issue